# Database failed to create: Error: Could not change password

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a database in Neo4j Desktop-1.0.19. When I click on create local graph button, it is asking me to give database name and set password for it. But, when I click the `Create` button, it is failing and throwing below error. Can anyone help me on this?

> Database failed to create: Error: Could not change password

Comment: There is already an issue on that : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11429

Comment: Its available, but the solution specified is not working..